# $f\circ g$ continuous, $f$ local homeomorphism, $g$ continuous in a different topology $\implies g$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

*I've [asked this question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272517) but neglected some assumptions and got a less than useful answer as a result, so I'm going to try again.*

> Let $g:I\times I\to Y$ (where $I=[0,1]$) be a function such that $g(0,-):I\to Y$ and $g(-,x):I\to Y$ for each $x\in I$ are continuous, $f:Y\to Z$ be a local homeomorphism, and suppose $h=f\circ g$ is a continuous function. Show that $g$ is continuous.

The condition on $g$ can also be understood as the statement that $g$ is continuous in the comb-like topology on $I\times I$ generated by open sets of the form $\{0\}\times U$ or $U\times\{x\}$ where $U$ is open in $I$. Importantly (I think), this topology is connected (although not locally connected).

The statement is "intuitively obvious" but I'm having trouble with the proof. Here is a partial proof assuming the following lemma, which basically "localizes" the original statement:

> Lemma (unproven): For any $(x,y)$ there is a neighborhood $U\times V\ni(x,y)$ such that if there is a $x'\in U$ such that $g$ is continuous in the subspace topology on $\{x'\}\times V$ (or alternatively, $y'\in V\mapsto g(x',y')$ is continuous), then $g$ is continuous on $U\times V$.

Let $C=\{(x,y)\mid g\mbox{ is continuous at }(x,y)\}$ and $A=\{x\in I:\{x\}\times I\subseteq C\}$. It is sufficient to prove that $A=I$, and by the Lemma, $g(0,-)$ is continuous implies $0\in A$. We will prove that $A$ is clopen; from this it follows that $A=I$ since $I$ is connected. Let $x\in I$. We wish to show that there is a neighborhood $U\ni x$ such that for all $x'\in U$, $x'\in A\leftrightarrow x\in A$.

Define $S_x=\{(x',y)\mid\exists V\ni y\,(\{x\}\times V\subseteq C\leftrightarrow\{x'\}\times V\subseteq C)\}$. Then $S_x^\circ$ is an open set, so by the tube lemma (using compactness of $I$), if $\{x\}\times I\subseteq S_x^\circ$ then there is a neighborhood $U$ such that $U\times I\subseteq S_x^\circ\subseteq S_x$, and then for all $x'\in U$, the definition of $S_x$ implies $x'\in A\leftrightarrow x\in A$ as desired.

It remains to prove that $\{x\}\times I\subseteq S_x^\circ$. Let $y\in I$; then by the Lemma there is a neighborhood $(x,y)\in U\times V$ with the property that if $\{x'\}\times V\subseteq C$ (which is slightly stronger than continuity of $y'\in V\mapsto g(x',y')$) then $U\times V\subseteq C$; to see that $U\times V\subseteq S_x$ note that if $\{x'\}\times V\subseteq C$ then $\{x\}\times V\subseteq C$ and vice versa because each one implies $U\times V\subseteq C$.

Comment: The Lemma could also be formulated as:
If every product neighborhood of $(x,y)$ contains an $x'$ such that $g$ is continuous on $x'\times I$, then there is a product neighborhood on which $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @StefanHamcke That sounds weaker than my version of the lemma. Are you saying that it is equivalent to the lemma, or that the rest of the proof can be restructured to use the weaker statement?

Comment: As for me, Lemma seems to be non-natural for separately continuous maps, such as the map $g$.

Comment: I found the formulation of the lemma a bit hard to grasp, so I tried to find a different formulation of it. I can show you the logical conversions which led me from one statement to the other.

Comment: And I haven't finished going through your proof, so I cannot yet say whether some weaker version of the lemma is enough.

Comment: @AlexRavsky The way I understand the Lemma is by reducing the original statement from $I\times I$ to $U\times V$; instead of having $g(0,-)$ and $g(-,x)$ continuous, we have $g(x',-)$ and $g(-,x)$ continuous within the subspace $U\times V$ (and of course the assumptions on $f$ and $h$ are the same when relativized to a subspace). My expectation is that it is sufficient to take $U\times V$ to be a neighborhood on which $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @StefanHamcke I think I see what you mean. When I attempt such conversion, I get: If every product neighborhood $U\times V$ of $(x,y)$ contains an $x'$ such that $g$ is continuous on $x'\times V$, then there is a product neighborhood on which $g$ is continuous. How did you extend from $x'\times V$ to $x'\times I$?

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes I meant $g$ is continuous on $x'\times V$.

Comment: In the definition of $S_x$, do you want $V$ to be an open set?

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes, read that as "there is a neighborhood of $y$ such that"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the Lemma, and hence the full statement, is indeed true under the following additional assumption:

> Around every point $y\in Y$ there is an open neighborhood $W$ such that $f:W\to f[W]$ is a homeomorphism, $f[W]$ is open, *and $W$ is closed in $f^{-1}[f[W]]$*.

(This is provable if $f$ is a covering map, and might even be equivalent to $f$ being a covering map, I'm not sure.) The proof is completed along the lines of the OP. The key step is the following fact about connected topologies:

> $(*)$ If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $X$ is connected, $U\subseteq Y$ is clopen and for some $x$, $f(x)\in U$, then $f:X\to U$.

The proof is a simple consequence of the connectedness of $f[X]$.

Turning to the lemma, given $(x,y)$ we have $g(x,y)\in Y$, so there is a neighborhood $W\ni g(x,y)$ on which $f$ is a homeomorphism, and then by continuity of $h$ there is a neighborhood $U\times V$ such that $h[U\times V]\subseteq f[W]$. Additionally (using local connectedness of $I$ or by choosing $U$ and $V$ to be open intervals), we can ensure that $U$ and $V$ are connected. Now suppose that $x'$ is given such that $g\restriction\{x'\}\times V$ is continuous; we wish to prove that $g\restriction U\times V$ is continuous.

First, we prove $g[U\times V]\subseteq W$. Note that $g[U\times V]\subseteq f^{-1}[f[W]]$ because $f[g[U\times V]]=h[U\times V]\subseteq f[W]$. Let $(z,w)\in U\times V$.

- Since $g\restriction U\times \{y\}:U\times \{y\}\to f^{-1}[f[W]]$ is continuous and $g(x,y)\in W$, by $(*)$ we also have $g(x',y)\in W$.
- Since $g\restriction \{x'\}\times V:\{x'\}\times V\to f^{-1}[f[W]]$ is continuous and $g(x',y)\in W$, by $(*)$ we also have $g(x',w)\in W$.
- Since $g\restriction U\times \{w\}:U\times \{w\}\to f^{-1}[f[W]]$ is continuous and $g(x',w)\in W$, by $(*)$ we also have $g(z,w)\in W$.

Since $z,w$ were arbitrary, this shows $g[U\times V]\subseteq W$. (We could also have shown, as suggested in the OP, that the topology generated by $\{x'\}\times V'$ and $U'\times\{y\}$ for each $U'$ open in $U$, $V'$ open in $V$, $y\in V$ is connected, and then gotten by with just one application of $(*)$.)

The rest is straightforward. Since $g\restriction U\times V:U\times V\to W$ it is sufficient to prove that $g$ is continuous in the subspace topology on $W$, so that for every open $W'\subseteq W$, $(g\restriction U\times V)^{-1}[W']$ is open in $U\times V$:
\begin{align}
(g\restriction U\times V)^{-1}[W']&=(g\restriction U\times V)^{-1}[(f\restriction W)^{-1}[(f\restriction W)[W']]]\\
&=((f\restriction W)\circ(g\restriction U\times V))^{-1}[(f\restriction W)[W']]\\
&=(f\circ(g\restriction U\times V))^{-1}[(f\restriction W)[W']]\\
&=((f\circ g)\restriction U\times V)^{-1}[(f\restriction W)[W']]\\
&=(h\restriction U\times V)^{-1}[(f\restriction W)[W']],
\end{align}

which is manifestly open.